# Parameterized for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I need to write a parameterized for loop.

```
# This works but...
df["ID"]=np_get_defined(df["methodA"+"ID"], df["methodB"+"ID"],df["methodC"+"ID"])

# I need a for loop as follows
df["ID"]=np_get_defined(df[sm+"ID"] for sm in strmethods)
```

and I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Remaining definitions:

```
import numpy as np
```

`df` is a Pandas.DataFrame

```
strmethods=['methodA','methodB','methodC']

def get_defined(*args):
    strs = [str(arg) for arg in args if not pd.isnull(arg) and 'N/A' not in str(arg) and arg!='0']
    return ''.join(strs) if strs else None
np_get_defined = np.vectorize(get_defined)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df["ID"]=np_get_defined(df[sm+"ID"] for sm in strmethods)` means you're passing a generator as single argument to the called method.

If you want to expand the generated sequence to a list of arguments use the `*` operator:

```
df["ID"] = np_get_defined(*(df[sm + "ID"] for sm in strmethods))
# or:
df["ID"] = np_get_defined(*[df[sm + "ID"] for sm in strmethods])
```

The first uses a generator and unpacks its elements, the second uses a list comprehension instead, the result will be the same in either case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why it doesn't work is that your `DataFrame` consists of columns with different lengths.